# How to change the image onClick. I want to apply a feature on my application where onclick I need to change the current image

Tags: qt, qml

I am working with qml, I want to apply a like feature on my application so I want to replace a black  image with the red image, when i click on the black image.

```
Image {
    id: like_img
    source: "image/oneImage.png"
    height: 18
    width: 20
    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
    
    MouseArea{
        id:mousearea                                   
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            like_img.source="images/anotherImage.png"                  
        } 
    }
 }
```

But the problem is When i again clicking on orange image I want the previous black image back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the looks of it, you are going to connect this to a backend, which actually should drive the `favorite` property, but for the time-being you can start with this:

```
Image {
    id: like_img
    source: favorite ? "image/oneImage.png" : "images/anotherImage.png"
    height: 18
    width: 20
    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
    
    property bool favorite : false

    MouseArea{
        id: mousearea                                   
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            like_img.favorite = !like_img.favorite
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Check the onclicked function contains desired image link or not like red image link.